# How do I allow my method to read my main

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EP55Out
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.print("Please enter a grade: ");
        String letter = in.next();
//         getNumericGrade(grade);
    }
    public static void getNumericGrade(double grade)
    {
        int spacer = 0;
        String first = letter.substring(0,1);
        String second = letter.substring(1,2);

        if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
        grade = 4.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        grade = 3.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        grade = 2.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
        grade = 1.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
        grade = 0;
        else grade = 9;

        if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
        grade += 0.3;
        else if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
        grade -= 0.3;
        else
        grade += 9;
        System.out.println(grade);
    }
}
```

I don't know if you guys understand what I mean, but I keep getting the error that "grade" does not exist even though it is defined in the main. I know it has something to do with "void" but I have no clue what. Can anybody help?

Comment: where you define grade variable.Can you show us ? I dont think it is defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't define it, but how would I define it in this case?

Comment: I've added the [tag:homework] tag, feel free to remove it if this isn't homework.

Comment: Please spend some time reading a Java tutorial. I'm not trying to be insulting, it's just that learning code by trial and error isn't generally the best way to understand the basics of coding. Sun's [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) are a fantastic resource.

Comment: what is your requirement with grade variable.According to your use and datatype you can define.

Comment: Where is grade defined? I guess you would want to pass the "letter"(casted to double) to getNumericGrade().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are learning Java don't you?

I'll try to explain what you are doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EP55Out {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.print("Please enter a grade: ");
        String letter = in.next();
        //You need to give letter to the method
        getNumericGrade(letter);
    }

    //AND the method should need String and not double 
    public static void getNumericGrade(String letter){      
    //After this you need a real double value - lets call is grade;
        double grade = 0;
        int spacer = 0;
        String first = letter.substring(0,1);
        String second = letter.substring(1,2);

        //You cant to numeric stuff with a String- thats why we use our double here
        if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
        grade = 4.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        grade = 3.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        grade = 2.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
        grade = 1.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
        grade = 0;
        else grade = 9;

        if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
        grade += 0.3;
        else if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
        grade -= 0.3;
        else
        grade += 9;
        System.out.println(grade+"");
    }
}
```

You missed an important point with variables...
If you define a variable in a method - it is only visible in THE DEFINING METHOD!

So 
    public static void getNumericGrade(String letter)
cannot know that there is a letter variable in 
    public static void main(String[] args)

Hope I could help you ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess the only thing I was missing was a definition of grade and all I had to do was to add: "double grade = 0;"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, and If u r getting error on the line that u have commented...

then "grade" really does not exist, The name of variable is `"letter"`

can u plz try running this code and see if it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
            System.out.print("Please enter a grade: ");
            String letter = in.next();
            getNumericGrade(letter);
        }
        public static void getNumericGrade(String letter)
        {
            int spacer = 0;
            double grade;
            String first = letter.substring(0,1);
            String second = letter.substring(1,2);

            if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            grade = 4.0;
            else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
            grade = 3.0;
            else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
            grade = 2.0;
            else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
            grade = 1.0;
            else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            grade = 0;
            else grade = 9;

            if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
            grade += 0.3;
            else if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
            grade -= 0.3;
            else
            grade += 9;
            System.out.println(grade);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry, the line that I commented it something else, I am getting an error starting from "grade = 4.0;"

Answer (score 0):

`grade` is not defined in main.  What you are looking for is `letter`,

```
String letter = in.next();
getNumericGrade(letter);
```

However, this will not solve your problem, as the `getNumericGrade` method requires you to pass it a double.  I think (based on the method name), that you really want `getNumericGrade` to accept a String, and return a double.  I would try referring to your textbook or tutorial some more, as you haven't grasped methods quite yet I don't think.

In particular, the `void` means that a method doesn't return a value.  `void` can be replaced with any type, like `int` or `String` or even `SomeClass`.  On the same line, inside the parentheses is where you specify what **arguments** your method will accept.  These can be of any type, and you can name them anything you want, *they don't have to correspond to the names of the variables you pass to a method call*.  So, if I had a method `getAverageGrade` which accepted a `String` argument (say the name of a student) and returned a `double` which is the current average grade for that student, the method signature, or definition would look something like this

```
public double getAverageGrade(String studentName)
```

Hopefully that should get you started down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should do like this way

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EP55Out
{
    String letter = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.print("Please enter a grade: ");
        letter = in.next();
        getNumericGrade();
    }
    public static void getNumericGrade()
    {
        if(letter.length()<=0)
           return;

        int spacer = 0;
        String first = letter.substring(0,1);
        String second = letter.substring(1,2);

        if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
        grade = 4.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        grade = 3.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
        grade = 2.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
        grade = 1.0;
        else if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
        grade = 0;
        else grade = 9;

        if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
        grade += 0.3;
        else if (second.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
        grade -= 0.3;
        else
        grade += 9;
        System.out.println(grade);
    }
}
```